# NHibernate - generate an update script from a different project

Tags: nhibernate, nant

I'm trying to generate an update script from my NHibernate models and mappings so that I can put the update script into a delta script, and allow my database to be created and updated from nant.

I can get the update script generated by using the following method:

```
private static IList<string> GetUpdateScript(Configuration configuration, string dbConnectionString)
        {
            var dialect = Dialect.GetDialect(configuration.Properties);
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                return configuration.GenerateSchemaUpdateScript(dialect,
                                          new DatabaseMetadata(connection, dialect))
                                          .ToList();
            }
        }
```

But then I was wanting to do this from a project outside of my current project, which is what I'm having trouble doing.

I guess the issue is about creating the Configuration object from a different project - maybe I'll research into this - I can imagine looking into the NHibernate code now...

Any ideas about how to approach this problem?

============================================================================
OK, here's an update:

I've created a project on github if you'd like to take a look: https://github.com/LouisSayers/NHibernateExample

The project has a Program.cs in the TheProject project, which is a working example, and the NHibernateUpdateScriptGenerator has a Program.cs which is the bit that has the error.

The problem is now that when I call Configure from the Configuration object, nhibernate complains about the dialect not being found, however I have the dialect defined in my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">
      NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,
      NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect,
      NHibernate
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">db</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>
    <mapping assembly="TheProject"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the hibernate.cfg.xml in each project that can be executed. Alternatively you can look at using the new [Loquacious configuration](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/01/21/loquacious-configuration-in-nhibernate-3.aspx) in NH3. Or [FluentNhibernate's fluent configuration](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Database_configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly saying what file has the configuration in it solved the problem - I was under the impression that 'hibernate.cfg.xml' would be looked at by default, but it doesn't seem so... The following was what I added to solve the issue with the dialect: var nhConfig = configuration.Configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

See http://github.com/LouisSayers/NHibernateExample for more details